# How can I resume video at the middle of video stream?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

In Documents, GCKRemoteMediaClient has play(), pause(). not resume()
And play()'s description is "Playback always begins at the beginning of the stream."

So, How can I resume video at the middle of video stream?
(I wanna pause -> resume)

setPlaybackrate also is not working..

In my custom class

```
func pause() {
    let request = castSession?.remoteMediaClient?.pause()
    request?.delegate = self

 // not work
 // let request = castSession?.remoteMediaClient?.setPlaybackRate(0)
 // request?.delegate = self
}

func play() {
    let request = castSession?.remoteMediaClient?.play()
    request?.delegate = self

    // not work
    // let request = castSession?.remoteMediaClient?.setPlaybackRate(1)
    // request?.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Do not repeat tags in title please. You have tags. That’s enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the description of Cast SDK, you need call `play`(objective c) function and the video will be resumed. You can read more from this [link](https://developers.google.com/cast/v3/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_remote_media_client.html#afc99d34ceaa076361ca52b990f8d71f2).

If you want to resume your video from the middle of the video, you should use `seek` function to do that.

> `/**
>    * Begins (or resumes) playback of the current media item. Playback always begins at the
>    * beginning of the stream. The request will fail if there is no current media status.
>    *
>    * @return The GCKRequest object for tracking this request.
>    */
>   - (GCKRequest *)play;`